# Rails 3 - Do I need to specify attr_accessible in my models for each attribute I want to use in create()?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm fairly new to rails and I am viewing some other's code. I notice that if I attempt to create an instance of a model object using create() I get an error telling me that I cannot create model objects using mass assignment. I am aware of the dangers associated with mass assignment in object creation. However this does not seem to be necessary in some of the source I am using as a reference. Is this new to rails 3.2.7?? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

So if I have a model called "Person" and I want to create a new one:

```
person = Person.create(:first_name => "Some", :last_name => "Dude") #throws exception
```

What I have been doing is adding this to the Person class definition:

```
attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name

person = Person.create(:first_name => "Some", :last_name => "Dude") #now this is OK
```

Is defining the accessible attributes on each model class the correct way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is new in rails 3.2 due to the security upgrade. you can learn more at [hackers love massignment](http://railscasts.com/episodes/26-hackers-love-mass-assignment)

```
attr_accessible :first_name,  :last_name
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html

Comment: So.. you are saying that it is necessary to specify the attributes in each model class?

Comment: yes or you can just set the attributes you want to be white listed.

Comment: any attribute u dont set will not be mass assigned and you. so u keep getting the mass assignment error. which simply means that attributes u set through a params hash will only work for those that are mass assigned for that model.

Comment: @SiweiShen I am trying to create new model objects in rails console just like in my post and it will not let me unless these attributes are explicitly defined in attr_accessible. rails -v 3.2.7 Are you sure you aren't using an older version?

Comment: @Nick My fault, I am using 3.2.2, but not 3.2.8. I checked the code,  yes , Uchenna is correct, the attr_accessible is needed in 3.2.8.

Answer (score 3):

As of Rails 3.2 we have a new config setting in application.rb:

`config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true`

What this is essentially doing is assuming all your models attributes are guilty until proven innocent(whitelisted). If this is set to true you have to explicitly white list any given attribute by either:

1. Whitelisting "safe" attributes which aren't vulnerable by including them as attr_accessible.
2. Explicitly blacklisting unsafe attributes which you don't want hackers to have direct access to. This assumes all non-blacklisted attributes are safe.

Generally it's good practice to keep this configuration setting to true and explicitly whitelist your attributes so you don't leave your application vulnerable to hackers.

See http://railspikes.com/2008/9/22/is-your-rails-application-safe-from-mass-assignment for additional reading on why you should take the recommended approach.

Comment: Right. I can see how mass assignment could open you up to a hack. Thanks